# Problem with db.function when running any command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am having a problem with db.function on messageCreate.js, before the bot was running pretty much okay, it does run okay now, but when I write a comment into discord let's say prefixplay waka waka or something it does give me that error however, I haven't even changed it before, I am running `discord.js@13.12.0`
can someone explain what the problem is?

Here is the code I have in `MessageCreate.js`

```js
module.exports = async (client, message) => {
  try {
    module.exports.messageGET = message;
    if (message.channel.type == "DM") return;
    let data = db.fetch(`SeTupInFo_${message.guild.id}`);
    if (data !== null) {
      if (message.channel.id == data.channelID) {
        message.delete();
        if (message.guild.me.voice.channel) {
          if (message.member.voice.channel !== message.guild.me.voice.channel)
            return message.reply({
              content: emojis.error + " | please join a voice channel first!",
            });
        }
```

Here is the error I am getting when I run any command

```
TypeError: db.fetch is not a function
    at module.exports (C:\Users\ramyo\Downloads\latestbottest1_feb-main\latestbottest1_feb-main\source\events\messageCreate.js:19:19)
    at Client.emit (node:events:537:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\ramyo\Downloads\latestbottest1_feb-main\latestbottest1_feb-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:25:14)
    at module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\ramyo\Downloads\latestbottest1_feb-main\latestbottest1_feb-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\ramyo\Downloads\latestbottest1_feb-main\latestbottest1_feb-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:350:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\ramyo\Downloads\latestbottest1_feb-main\latestbottest1_feb-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\ramyo\Downloads\latestbottest1_feb-main\latestbottest1_feb-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
    at C:\Users\ramyo\Downloads\latestbottest1_feb-main\latestbottest1_feb-main\node_modules\@discordjs\voice\dist\index.js:604:32
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I tried many thinks, and even also tried downgrade dependencies to my old ones that were working before, its some think not expecting any output that the command is working please help thank you.

Comment: What's `db`? I'd start there.

Comment: quick.db version 7.1.3 when i am using quick.db latest version i get that error.. once i downgrade the db it works, but discord version 14 it does not

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's a valid function, my guess would be that `db` hasn't been imported properly. Try something like `const db = require('db-package')` at the top of the file.